# Create C# Generic Method Mapping To Object Instance Lists

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, generics, type-conversion

## Create C# Generic Method Mapping To Object Instance Lists

### Problem

I'm attempting to create one or more generic C# methods that operate over a `Dictionary<long, string>,` capable of mapping `(long)Key` & `(string)Value` to
compatible `IEnumerable<T>` objects. Where `T` will be a class with two properties: `(long)Id` & `(string)Value`.

I'm not limited very much in terms of how I can approach the problem. The main goal is for the data structure to be mappable to classes sharing that shape. I've included code signatures/snippets as a rough outline.

### Outline

#### 1. Input Shape

[image: Starting Data Structure]

#### 2. Output Shape

[image]

#### 3. Method Shape

[image]

Comment: Please don't paste pictures of code. Just paste the code. It's common for people to actually open Visual Studio and write code to answer a question, or to make sure its accurate. That's much easier if they can paste your code into the editor. We can't do that with a picture.

Answer (score 1):

In a generic method, you can only do things with a reference of type `T` that you know about type `T`. How are you supposed to know that type `T` has those properties? The only way is for them to be declared in a common base class or interface and then you can constrain `T` to be that type.

For instance, you might have this interface:

```cs
public interface IThing
{
    long Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

You can then write this method:

```cs
public void DoSomething<T>(T arg) where T : IThing
{
    arg.Id = 0L;
    arg.Name = "Hello";
}
```

You can access those members in the method because of the constraint, which means that only objects whose type implements the `IThing` interface can be passed to that method.

If all the types you want to map to don't inherit a common base type or implement a common interface then you're out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

The method you want already exists - the [LINQ `Select` extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=net-7.0#system-linq-enumerable-select-2(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-func((-0-1)))). (`using System.Linq;`)

`Dictionary<long, string>` implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<long,string>>`. It already is a collection of objects with a `long` and `string` property.

With `Select` you can map those key/value pairs to a different type.

```cs
IEnumerable<MyClass> myResult =
    myDict.Select(keyValuePair => 
        new MyClass {Id = keyValuePair.Key, Name = keyValuePair.Value});
```

You're passing a in function that takes a `KeyValuePair<long,string>` and returns something - in this case an instance of `MyClass`. That function is

```cs
keyValuePair => 
        new MyClass {Id = keyValuePair.Key, Name = keyValuePair.Value}
```

...which is an anonymous function (it's just declared, it has no name) and the equivalent of

```cs
MyClass CreateFromKeyValuePair(KeyValuePair<long,string> keyValuePair)
{
    return new MyClass {Id = keyValuePair.Key, Name = keyValuePair.Value};
}
```

`Select` passes each item in the source (in this case, an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<long,string>>`) and returns an `IEnumerable<T>` where `T` is whatever the function returns.

Comment: Hey Scott, although this works if I specify the class, I would like this to be generic. Thus it would have to be like this:

`
 public static IEnumerable<T> BuildMyResultList(Dictionary<long, string> dictionary)
    {
        return IEnumerable<T> myResult =
            dictionary.Select(keyValuePair => 
                new T : {Id = keyValuePair.Key, Name = keyValuePair.Value});
    }
` 

Which unfortunately doesn't work.

Comment: The Select method is generic. The generic arguments aren't shown because they're inferred. Can T be something other than MyClass? What else could it be?